# Android layout editor background color gets ignored

Tags: android, android-layout

The following layout xml snippet works fine. But if I make any attempt to remove the Floating Action Button in it, the background color of "@color/green" in main Layout element gets ignored by the IDEA/Android Studio Layout Editor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:onClick="callDirector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"/>

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@color/green"
        tools:context="org.drachenschloss.bidzclient.MainActivity">
```

I'm perfectly content to remove both the FAB AND the CoordinatorLayout (if memory serves, I only put in the CoordinatorLayout for the FAB), thus moving all of the xmlns elements to the RelativeLayout as that would become the root layout element for the activity but that doesn't help either.

Again the green background color works fine in the app. It's just not shown in the IDE layout editor display. I've even tried adding

```
tools:background="@color/green"
```

in order to cause the root layout element (whichever it is) to make the layout display in IDEA get the clue, but nothing changes. The moment the FAB goes away, the background color for the activity does too.

Comment: This code works perfect for me. Try to run in real device.

Comment: Unable to reproduce this issue as you explained. It working fine for me. Clean Project and rebuild.

Comment: Like I said: It works perfectly in the emulator and on the device. Where it doesn't work is the design view of xml file in side of the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is a difficult to reproduce issue in both IJ and Android Studio.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62334380